# Chrome / Google Analytics - ga.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics

I looked at many similiar post here, but haven't found a solution for my problem. It's most likely something totally simple, but I just can't get it.

**Problem**
I have sevaral domains and use one Account in Google Analytics to track them. THey have cross links (basically between different languages). When I try to click a link to another of my domains nothing happens (unless I view it on the Chrom consol). Other browser work fine...

Some code
a) The snipplet provided by GA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'site1.de']);
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
 (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();
</script>
```

b) Then in the BODY I have following link:

```
<A HREF="http://www.site2.com/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.site2.com/']); return false;">English</A>
```

As said, clicking on that link is fine in eg IE, FF. But in Chrome nothing seems to happen. If I open the console I see an error:

> ga.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I also see a lot of 'chinese chracters' in information window.

Now if I either activate the GA Debug or use the ga_debug.js the code works fine.
I have tried to save the html file in different encodings (UTF-8, ANSI...) but that didn't do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: I tried to paste your code on jsfiddle and it works for me on chrome 14. No errors. http://jsfiddle.net/eduardocereto/X2U7X/

Comment: Probably you have some extension in Chrome that is interfering

Comment: When you set up Google Analytics, when they asked you "What are you tracking?" did you click the one for tracking across domain names?

Comment: Sounds like you have a corrupted/cached version of `.google-analytics.com/ga.js`

Try [clearing your cache](http://browsers.about.com/od/faq/f/Clear-Browser-Cache.htm)

Comment: This looks like some invalid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>ctrl + shift + n</kbd> to open a tab in safe mode, then load your URL there to verify whether an extension is causing the issue. If the error disappears, this is the root cause. Otherwise, use a data URI to check whether it's a corrupted font issue:

```
data:text/html,Helvetica<br><font face="Helvetica" size="25">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</font><br>
Helvetica Neue<br><font face="Helvetica Neue" size="25">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</font>
```

Replace `Helvetica Neue` with the font-face used by the web page.

**References**

- [Fixing Google Analytics for Ghostery](http://ejohn.org/blog/fixing-google-analytics-for-ghostery/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Ghostery extension which was causing this.